# May I transfer token address to ERC20 of openzeppelin's lib

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

For using openzeppelin's ERC20 one can tansfer token info by constructor.
But for token making by myself, it seems not work.
I can use something like

```
ERC20(token address).burnfrom(...)
```

for Public function in ERC20, but for private variables in ERC20, it does not work.

For example, I have made an ERC20 token "masaToken" at BSC testnet.
The token address is 0x3114DbeAE60a6Ea05d04A8b361B261990b04606e.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: no license
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyTokenContract is ERC20 {
    address MyToken = 0x3114DbeAE60a6Ea05d04A8b361B261990b04606e;

    constructor() ERC20("masaToken", "MASASET") {
    }


    function total1() public view returns (uint256){
        return totalSupply();
    }


    function total2() public view returns (uint256){

        return ERC20(MyToken).totalSupply();
    }
}
```

When I used above code to test it, I found that the correct token info cannot
be transfered by constructor.The result of total1() is 0， but total2() is 1000000000000000000000.

Answer (score 0):

To create your own ERC20 token and pass all the token info, you need to inherit from openzeppelins ERC20 token. It would look like this:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {

    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MYT") {

    }

}
```

---

Edit:
When you inherit from `ERC20`, you can increase your total supply by minting new token.

If you want to have fixed `totalSupply` you have to implement `IERC20` yourself and set your `totalSupply` property.

You can take a look at open-zeppelin ERC20 contract here: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Comment: @Masa I updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: ＠ashhanai　　　　　　　　Thank you very much.
For totalSupply, I can use IERC20, but for other function that need  
token address such as burn(), and burnfrom()
it seems not work. And there are not such function in IERC20.